# Blender 2.8 Displacement node not working

Tags: texturing, uv, displacement, vector-mapping

I am trying to add a displacement node to this mesh to get a brick wall but i can't seem to get it to work on this particular mesh and i don't know why. Can anybody give me some ideas because i looked everywhere for an answer and i still cant get it to work.

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your mesh have subdivisions? Dislplacement will not work with just 4 vertices on a plane.

Comment: it does it has a tone of subdivisions.

Comment: it needs more subdivisions (or a Subsurf modifier) and a bit more Displacement Scale value

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The displacement is too weak, you're seeing it in the others because of the scale of the object.

Apply the scale (alt+A) in any mesh that it worked that you will see that the displacement effect is gone.

In the same way, press S+Z in the mesh of the pic and you will see the displacement

And you also need to be in Cycles "rendered" view to see it. The Shading preview will always use Eevee

[image]

Comment: i did apply scale numerous times, and the displacement Scale is at 0.9 which if anything should be too high.  And the Render engine is Cycles unless i am missing something.. I don;t quite understand what you mean by pressing 'S+Z in the mesh'

Comment: The scale of the displacement must be higher, OR you must increase the scale of the plane in the Z axis in object mode (S+Z =Scale + Z).

Can you see the gifs what I've done in your file?

Comment: https://youtu.be/EENrG_uoeTw here's exacly what I did since I opened your file

Comment: yes but up to 0:45 the bricks don't displace orderly, the entire mesh displaces when in fact only the darker patches (the bricks) should displace. I just can't get it to work with a displacement node.

Comment: oh now I understand better your problem. Yet, I got the correct shape of by adding more subdvisions

Comment: It got a lot heavier than the other mesh, for some reason, but the displacement node is working normally. https://youtu.be/cMjIYs1SjT8